# How to align vertically a middle alert dismiss button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to align vertically middle bootstrap alert dismiss button?

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info" role="alert">
<div class="alert-message">
Multi<br>
Line<br>
Alert
</div>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b5asr9xj/4/

div alert-message is there just because I'm using jQuery.html to update content in it...

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your text in `<p></p>` tags and then set `text-align: center;` on them.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5asr9xj/6/)

Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align it. Vertically in the middle you can do something like this with your current html.

```
.alert-message {
   text-align: center;


button{

   display: inline-block;

}
```

within your alert-message class you align the text to the center and you can then make it display inline(vertical).

see [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5asr9xj/7/)

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this for vertically middle.
Add parent div to position: relative;
See demo link here. https://jsfiddle.net/rhwxm3md/1/

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info" role="alert">
<div class="alert-message">
Multi<br>
Line<br>
Alert
</div>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.alert-info {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bce8f1;
  color: #31708f;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```